# Getting sql syntax error while searching value with single and double in my sql through sequelize raw query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
Sequelize. query (`SELECT
users.firstName,
users.lastName
FROM users
WHERE CONCAT(users.firstName,'',users.lastName) LIKE 'jho'nn"y%'`,{select statement}
```

)

The above query gives syntax error with above value,if I search with **jhonny** it's working fine

Comment: Why `'jho'nn"y%'`? Please describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's a test case where it is failing ,just want sent empty data where string is not available in db

Comment: the part `,'',` within concat function is redundant.

Comment: @barbaros how can I solve this ,actually  I am new to my sql

Comment: I mean, if you do `SELECT 'jho'nn"y%'`, you'll get error something like `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"y%'' at line 1` so.. its also not usable in anywhere else in the query

Comment: update your question and a proper data sample  .. is not clear the like codition you are trying to  use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for `joh'nnyAndLastname` then you culd use

```
WHERE CONCAT(users.firstName,'',users.lastName) LIKE "jho'nny%"
```

or

```
LIKE 'jho\'nn"y%'
```

Comment: if single quote comes with double quotes for eg **jho'nn"y**